# How to Put Data into Data Frames Without Repeating Code in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, tibble

I have a url which can be updated by manually typing something into `updated_url`. Then, the data from this url is extracted and placed into a tibble.

However, my current code looks inefficient because it's repeated. Is there a way to e.g. put this in a loop so that it isn't repetitive? Essentially, I just want to type something into the updated url bit (here, it's X and Y) and have two tibbles returned (`tibble1` and `tibble2`) without having to repeat the tibble code.

```
updated_url <- url_function('X')

tibble1 <- fromJSON(update_url) %>% 
  pluck(2) %>% 
  as_tibble()

updated_url <- url_function('Y')

tibble2 <- fromJSON(update_url) %>% 
  pluck(2) %>% 
  as_tibble()
```

Help appreciated!

Comment: What is `url_function` ?

Comment: @akrun it's a function used elsewhere that refers to a url (e.g. google.com/), and typing e.g. X into `updated_url` turns it into e.g. google.com/X. Then data at this website is taken and put into a tibble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple looping question. There are many ways to do a loop in R, but I think an idiomatic way is with an `lapply` function here:

```
vec <- c("X", "Y")

tb_list <- lapply(vec, function(x) {
  updated_url <- url_function(x)
  fromJSON(update_url) %>% 
    pluck(2) %>% 
    as_tibble()
})
```

`tb_list` will be a list of tibbles, with one tibble for each element of `vec`.

Comment: Thank you, this works! Is there a way to view the tibbles separately? Because this method combines them, so e.g. `view(tb_list)` shows a data frame with both combined.

Comment: You can `bind_rows()`, which will join them

Comment: is there a way to name the tibbles? In the original post, I could name them tibble1 and tibble2. Is that possible here too?

Comment: You can always do `tibble1 <- tb_list[[1]]; tibble2 <- tb_list[[2]]`, but I'm not sure that's necessary. You can always access them individually using `tb_list[[1]]` and `tb_list[[2]]`

Answer (score 1):

Using `map` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(vec, ~   url_function(.x)
              fromJSON(.) %>% 
             pluck(2) %>% 
             as_tibble()
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a vector to everything you want to pass to `url_function`, i'll call it `vec`. Then use a for loop to add each table into a list (you could create a variable for each tibble with `assign`, but i don't recommend it):

```
newlist <- list()
for(i in vec){
  updated_url <- url_function(i)

  tibble <- fromJSON(update_url) %>% 
    pluck(2) %>% 
    as_tibble()

  newlist[[i]] <- tibble}
```